# What is the equivalent of bind_result on PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm converting to PDO and Im using prepared statements, I want to bind my result as so `$stmt->bind_result($email_count);` so i am able to put this into an if statement to see if the e-mail exists however I am getting the error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_result() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/imanage/insert.php on line 51` which relates to the previous example.

I'm guessing bind_result is not a PDO defined method, so is there an equivalent I could use?

My code is below in case it helps:

insert.php

```
<?php

 include("connect/class.Database.php");

 class Users extends Database {

     public function insert() {

            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email=:email");
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
            $stmt->bind_result($email_count);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if ($email_count > 0) {
                        echo "email exisits! click here to try <a href='register'>again</a>";
                        } else {
                            //escape the POST data for added protection
                            $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
                            $cryptedPassword = crypt($_POST['password']);
                            $password = $cryptedPassword;
                            $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
                            $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;

                            $data = array($username, $password, $name, $email); 
                            $stmta = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                            $stmta->execute($data);

                                printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmta->row_count);
                                /* close statement and connection */
                                $stmta->close();
                } // end email_count and insert to table
            } // end function

      }
?>
```

connect/class.Database.php

```
<?php

// Database connection PDO

class Database {

    public function __construct() {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'imanage';
        $user   = 'root';
        $pass   = '';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

     public function __destruct()
    {
        // Disconnect from DB
        $this->pdo = null;
        echo 'Successfully disconnected from the database!';
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: bind_result looks like a MySQLi function: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php which means you can't probably mix and match pdo functions with MySQLi and vice versa.

Comment: `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns an associative array, unlike `fetch()` in a mysqli call, which expects variable references. You can just take the array returned by a call like `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`  To see what you got, `print_r($row);`

Comment: This is how bind works in PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php (also look at other bind functions on that page)

Comment: Review the [`PDOStatement::fetch()` docs for examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)... it's generally easier to use than MySQLi.

Comment: ok thanks but then how do i store the count of the email? so that I can alert the user that this email already exists? @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @gutigrewal With your current query, it would be in `$row['COUNT(*)']` if done as in my earlier example. However, it is recommended to alias that column `SELECT COUNT(*) AS the_count....` in your query, then retrieve `$row['the_count']`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski sorry im fairly new to PHP so forgive my ignorance, how would i go about creating an alias for that column?

Comment: Just as in my comment above. AS the_count

Comment: @gutigrewal in PDO you have $stm->count(); which will give the number of rows affected/returned by the last query

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita I think you mean `rowCount()` and for a `SELECT COUNT()` query (and only for MySQL), this would only return 1

Comment: It's just so refreshing seeing somebody use a `COUNT` query rather than the mostly incorrect `PDOStatement::rowCount` method. Nicely done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### You do not need an ugly bind_result with PDO at all.

Yet you don't need to count either. Please, avoid unnecessary actions - they only bloat and obfuscate your code for no reason.

Think first, what you need from the query? Do you really need to count? No. What you actually need is just a flag - if user exists or no. So, make a query to return such a flag.

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['email']));
$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Same goes for all the other parts of code

```
//escape the POST data for added protection
```

You don't actually "escape" any data in this code block and add no protection. Yet I see absolutely no point in inserting NULL as email. Are you sure you really want it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense is this line now redundant `$stmta->close();`? or does the query automatically close?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, also I have null on the line         $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null; as without this on mysqli prepared statement it was not inserting the data correctly, it was inserting a numerical value instead of the actual value

Comment: @gutigrewal A statement that only returns at most, one row, will be closed automatically after the first fetch operation so yes, using `$stmt->closeCursor()` is redundant in this case

Comment: @gutigrewal  Most of time you don't have to bother. When you have a **dedicated method** that runs your query and returns the result - it will be a good practice to close. But as long as you are using raw PDO - don't bother.

Comment: @gutigrewal speaking od these NULLs - you are confusing something for sure. Speaking od DB connection - the main idea is to have only **ONE** connection per application. Which way you achieve it is not that important. But you have to make sure you are connecting only once

Answer (score 5):

For quickly retrieving a value from something like a `SELECT COUNT()` query, have a look at [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn`](http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), eg

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE email = :email');
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
$email_count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

I'd also like to offer some further advice. You shouldn't be creating a `PDO` connection in your class constructor. This means that every time you instantiate a class extending `Database`, you create a new connection. Instead, pass the `PDO` instance as a dependency, eg

```
abstract class Database {
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
}
```

The same goes for your `User::insert` method. Try to pass any required parameters via method arguments. If you ever want to start writing unit tests for your classes, this will be invaluable

```
public function insert($email) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $email_count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    // and so on
```

And finally, for PHP only files, omit the closing PHP tag `?>`. This will save you from accidentally including whitespace at the end of your files that may be sent to the browser.

Comment: thanks, in regards to the database class should I my db connection be in a separate function to the construct? basically like above but not in the construct?

Answer (score 2):

For people who come here seeking a literal answer.

[**Use `bindColumn`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php)

> PDOStatement::bindColumn — Bind a column to a PHP variable

using the example from the same source :

> ```
> function readData($dbh) {
>   $sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories FROM fruit';
>   try {
>     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
>     $stmt->execute();
>
>     /* Bind by column number */
>     $stmt->bindColumn(1, $name);
>     $stmt->bindColumn(2, $colour);
>
>     /* Bind by column name */
>     $stmt->bindColumn('calories', $cals);
>
>     while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
>       $data = $name . "\t" . $colour . "\t" . $cals . "\n";
>       print $data;
>     }
>   }
>   catch (PDOException $e) {
>     print $e->getMessage();
>   }
> }
> readData($dbh);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my custom function:

```
function bindColumns($stmt, $columns){
    if(!is_array($columns)) $columns=array($columns);
    $count=count($columns);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) $stmt->bindColumn($i+1, $columns[$i]);
}
```

And usage (variables by reference):

```
bindColumns($stmt, array(&$worker_id, &$password, &$salt));
```