# How to use php List function with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I am currently updating php code to use PDO. The legacy code is:

```
list($category_name,$parentid) = 
mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(sprintf(" select name, parentid_fk from category 
where categoryid = '%s' ", mysql_escape($categoryid))));
```

I have so far updated it to:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select 
    name, parentid_fk
from 
    category
where 
    id = :categoryid
");
    $stmt->bindParam(":categoryid",$categoryid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();   
    list($category_name,$parentid) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I `echo $category_name` or `echo $parentid` the values come out null. Can anyone tell me how to use the php list function with PDO?

Thanks

Comment: [What is the equivalent of bind_result on PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710948/4248328)

Answer (score 0):

One way is using [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Get result

extract($result);  // Extract result
echo $name;        // Prints name value
echo $parentid_fk; // Prints parentid_fk value
```