# How can I convert this mysqli to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

```
<?php

    require_once('dbconfig.php');
    global $con;

    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM userinfo order by id DESC");
    $query->execute();
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $id, $name, $username, $password);
```

Comment: Don't globalise `$con`, that's a huge security hole and is also bad practise from a coding point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `->bindColumn` [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php)

See also [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260754/3536236).

- Best Practise: Do not use `SELECT *` instead define each column you need to grab from the table.
- Do not globalise your connection variable. This is a security risk as well as adding bloat and should be unneeded on your code.
- Because it is a static statement you can use `->query` rather than `prepare`, as nothing needs to be prepared.

## Solution:

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT id,name,username,password FROM userinfo ORDER BY id DESC");
try {
   $query->execute();
   $query->bindColumn(1, $id);
   $query->bindColumn(2, $name); 
   $query->bindColumn(3, $username); 
   $query->bindColumn(4, $password); 
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
   error_log(print_r($ex,true);
}
```

## Alternatively:

> A nice feature of PDO::query() is that it enables you to iterate over the rowset returned by a successfully executed SELECT statement.  [From the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

```
foreach ($conn->query('SELECT id,name,username,password FROM userinfo ORDER BY id DESC') as $row) {
    print $row['id'] . " is the ID\n";
    print $row['name'] . " is the Name\n";
    print $row['username'] . " is the Username\n";
}
```

## See Also:

[**Mzea**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63925452/3536236) Has some good hints on their answer, you should use their `$options` settings as well as using their suggested `utf8mb4` connection character set.

And their suggestion for using `->fetchAll` is also completely valid too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase;charset=utf8mb4";
$options = [
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
];
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password", $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Something weird happened'); //something a user can understand
}

$arr = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myTable")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Some good advice here. If you can add some text to explain it a little that would be great.